# how can we test a dalli/memcachier failure in Rails 3.2 Rspec request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, memcached

What is the best way to test a Dalli/Mamcache failure in RSpec/Capybara request specs to verify our app still works when the Dalli server fails?

We use Dalli (on a Heroku app) to handle caching of certain account data in our production app, eg, config/environments/production.rb contains:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

In the app in many places we use `Rails.cache.write` and `Rails.cache.fetch`

On a fairly regular basis, the Heroku Memcachier add-on service becomes non-responsive, and we see the following in our logs:

```
app[web.2]: xxx.xxx.xxx.heroku.prod.memcachier.com:xxxx failed (count: 0)
```

We have some request specs testing some fairly long user interaction scenarios that cover all uses of the Rails cache, and now need to add some additional specs that test how those scenarios behave when the remote Dalli store is broken... eg, we want to add specs that verify the entire app appropriately 'rescues' when we see the inevitable Memcachier service failure.

Currently, config/environments/test.rb has no setting for config.cache_store

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the best way, but what we did is:

```
  before (:each) do
        # test to ensure works OK if cache is broken due to heroku memcachier failure
      Rails.cache.stub(:write).and_raise("CACHE WRITE IS BROKEN")
      Rails.cache.stub(:fetch).and_raise("CACHE FETCH IS BROKEN")
      Rails.cache.stub(:read).and_raise("CACHE READ IS BROKEN")
      Rails.cache.stub(:delete).and_raise("CACHE DELETE IS BROKEN")
  end
```

When we temporarily disabled our exception handling in a few places and run the specs, the specs fail (as expected). So it does seem to do the trick.